# How to use AFNetworking to make a request of a SOAP with authentication,which returns son

Tags: ios, json, soap, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I have a soap web service with a authentication key and it returns json content.

this is the request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <FlightSearch xmlns="http://someurl.com/">
      <Authkey>string</Authkey>
      <from>string</from>
      <SesID>string</SesID>
    </FlightSearch>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

this is the response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <FlightSearchResponse xmlns="http://someurl.com/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

how can I use AFNetworking to consume data from the web service

Comment: More information required.  The example shows an empty SOAP response. There is no JSON to consume.

Comment: I made the request and got the response
`[{"sno":null,"AirportCode":"YQM","Airport":"Moncton Airport","City":"Moncton","Country":"Canada"}]<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetAirportResponse xmlns="http://mapi.uk/" /></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`

this is the response I got. @Roberto